# How to convert list to string?

Tags: haskell

I make a function which read file and removes in every line all the words that were encountered earlier in the same line.

```
{-# OPTIONS_GHC -Wall #-}
module Main where
import System.Environment
import System.IO()

main :: IO ()
main = do args <- getArgs 
          if (length args > 0) then do
            f <- get args
            putStrLn (seqWord $ head f)
          else do
            f <- getContents
            putStrLn (seqWord f)

get :: [String] -> IO[String]
get [] = return []
get (file:xs) = do
  contents <- readFile file
  fs <- get xs
  return (contents:fs)

seqWord :: String -> String
seqWord s = show (map (filterWord . words) (lines s))

filterWord :: [String] -> [String]
filterWord [] = []
filterWord (x:xs) = x : filterWord (filter(/=x) xs)
```

In answer I have list of lists, like this

```
[["1","12","5","8","13","145","85"],["546","822","1","12","58","8","9"]]
```

Please, help me fix this problem. Thank you

Comment: You may consider looking into `Data.List.Unique.unique` functionality as well. It will keep the last word and will remove the previous dupes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `unwords` function to undo the effect of `words`. You may also want to replace `show` with `unlines`.

```
seqWord s = unlines (map (unwords . filterWord . words) (lines s))
```

Comment: I add this. But I have problem. I have to read the file whose name is set on the command line. If there is no file then I have to read the content from stdin. But when I do the Enter in the console, I get the result, but it should return only after Ctrl C. Maybe you know how to solve the problem?

Comment: "when I do the Enter in the console, I get the result, but it should return only after Ctrl C" Ctrl-C will kill your program. Perhaps you mean an end-of-file indicator like Ctrl-D or Ctrl-Z. Why do you want this unusual behaviour? Your program is a typical line-oriented filter and works like one (compare with `grep` or `tr`).

Comment: Anyway the easiest way to delay printing would be to force evaluation of input (or output) string length and then ignore it, e.g. instead of `s` use `(seq (length s) s)`.